# Combine a point shapefile and a road shapefile in R

Tags: r, shapefile

I would like to know how do I combine two shapefile files, one being a Points shapefile and the other being a roads shapefile in the R software. In the attachment I left an image that I made combining the two shapefiles in the Arcgis software.

For testing, both shapefiles can be downloaded from the following website: https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/master/Example.zip

Thank you very much!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to just visualize the data then this is how you can do it. Note that your road and point shapefiles do not appear to have the same projection. Shapefiles can only hold one shape type (lines, points, polygons, etc.) so you can't really combine them.

```
library(sf)

roads <- st_read('Roads/Roads.shp')
pts <- st_read('Points/Points.shp') %>% 
  st_transform(crs=st_crs(roads))


plot(st_geometry(roads))
plot(st_geometry(pts), add = T, col = 'red', pch = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not understand when you said that they look like they are not in the same projection ?? One more thing, can I find out the distance between one point and the other and plot on that map? Thank you again

Comment: Each shapefile has a projection that specifies it's position in space relative to a datum both vertically and horizontally. For your shapefiles, if I don't use `st_transform()` to convert to the same crs, then `st_crs(roads) == st_crs(pts)` shows `FALSE` indicating that the projections are not the same. Also you can use `st_distance(pts, pts)` to get a distance matrix of each point from each point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I asked a question related to the code you made. I would like to know from one point to another, for example, point 4 and point 10.
The question follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662368/shortest-distance-in-r

Comment: Hello at80, any idea for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092033/issue-involving-map-generation-in-shiny