# Shortest distance in R

Tags: r, shortest-path, shapefile

I would like to know how to calculate the shortest distance between two properties (points) for my code below. There are two shapefile files, one being a points shapefile, the other a roads shapefile.

For testing, both shapefiles can be downloaded from the following website: https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/master/Example.zip

```
library(sf)

roads <- st_read('Roads/Roads.shp')
pts <- st_read('Points/Points.shp') %>% 
  st_transform(crs=st_crs(roads))


plot(st_geometry(roads))
plot(st_geometry(pts), add = T, col = 'red', pch = 20)
```

[image]

#### Example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `st_distance` to get a distance matrix and find the minimum. I wrote a function that can process all of that and return a new `sf` data.frame. The data.frame will contain attributes called `nearest` and `distance` which is the index of the nearest point and the distance to that point respectively. Note the distances are in meters reflecting your projection. Your data have repeating points, so some of the points show no distance because of that. If you don't want those points you will have to remove the duplicates.

```
getNearest <- function(shp){
  dist <- as.data.frame(st_distance(shp))
  for (i in 1:ncol(dist)){
    rows <- seq(1:ncol(dist))
    rows <- rows[i != rows]
    shp[i, 'nearest'] <- which.min(dist[rows, i])
    shp[i, 'distance'] <- dist[which.min(dist[rows, i]), i]
  }
  return(shp)
}

pts2 <- getNearest(pts)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Just a few questions for clarification: this distance found, is the Euclidean distance or is it the real distance? Do you have a formula to show only the distance between just two properties that I want, for example, I want to know only the distance between point 3 and 6? Thanks again

Comment: It should be euclidean. You can specify which inside `st_distance(which='Euclidean')`. Your projection is planar so  euclidean should work. If you use `?st_distance` it  tells the source under details. To find point 3 and 6 just use `st_distance(pts[c(3,6),])`. The answer will be the non-zero value.

Comment: Thank you at80. If I want to show only properties 3 and 6 on the map, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you just need to subset points inside of your plot command; replace `pts` with `pts[c(6,10), ]`.

Comment: Thanks again at80. One last question, I am thinking of asking a new question in Stackoverflow about it. But I would love to hear your opinion. For example, is it possible to make the path between property 3 and property 6 on this generated map, showing, for example, a red line highlighting the path between the two properties?

Comment: Yes, you need to union the points to a single geometry and cast it to a line, something like this. `connect <- st_cast(st_union(pts[c(6,10),]), to='LINESTRING')
plot(connect, add=TRUE, col='red')
` Note that this plot command needs to be above the points plot command to not plot over them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that I expressed myself badly., I meant a red line on the path traveled (road) between property 3 to property 6, and not a straight red line connecting one another.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to measure the distance along the road to each point and it's closest point. Please see a similar workflow here:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/distance-between-points-along-network-path/49596/2

Comment: Thanks hello_friend for reply. I will check